# Context Menu in WPF without XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I am trying to design an application with 256 button inside. These buttons are added by using "for" loop in c#, so they are not in the `XAML` code. My problem is that - I don't know how to add a Context Menu to such a button. The context menu should open when clicking right mouse button on particular button. Then I want to be able to change some variable in code, when selecting some of the context menu item.

My code for adding buttons is following:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    int num = number(3);

    for(int i =0; i<(num*num); i++)
    {
        //i want initialize the context menu here 
        Button button = new Button();

        button.Name = "Butt" + counter;

        button.Content = "New";

        counter++;
        button.Height = 35;
        button.Width = 35;
        button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(NewButton_Click);
        wp.Children.Add(button); // Wrap Panel where buttons displayed
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a context menu like this:

```
 ContextMenu c = new ContextMenu();
 MenuItem i1 = new MenuItem();
 i1.Header = "Some Header";
 i1.Click += i1_Click;
 c.Items.Add(i1);
```

and attach it to a button like this:

```
 button.ContextMenu = c;
```

Comment: Ok, but what exactly is i1_Click ?

Comment: The eventhandler for the click on the MenuItem. Similar to `NewButton_Click`, which is a eventhandler for the click on your new button.